# Return all rows from left table

Tags: sql, excel

Here's what I'm trying to get:

All customer accounts, even those who haven't placed orders.
Adjustable parameters

Data is from Sage, so I can't alter that.

All customer account numbers including those which haven't placed orders.
The sum of those orders

Criteria:
Those with orders under a certain value (this will be a user parameter)
Within certain dates (again, a user parameter)
No accounts on hold (this isn't present in the sample code below yet)

Basically, I want a list all the accounts in a certain time frame, which have spent under a certain amount. But for it to also include all accounts which haven't placed an order.

I've looked at various other threads on here, and tried replacing WHERE with AND but keep getting an error.

Pretty obvious, but data is pulling from Sage.

Heres the code:

```
SELECT SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountNumber, Sum(SLTransactionSummary.InvoiceValue) AS 'Sum of InvoiceValue'
FROM {oj SWA_live2.dbo.SLCustomerAccount SLCustomerAccount LEFT OUTER JOIN SWA_live2.dbo.SLTransactionSummary SLTransactionSummary ON SLCustomerAccount.SLCustomerAccountID = SLTransactionSummary.SLCustomerAccountID}
WHERE (SLTransactionSummary.TransactionDate Between ? And ?)
GROUP BY SLCustomerAccount.CustomerAccountNumber
HAVING (Sum(SLTransactionSummary.InvoiceValue) Between 0 And 50000)
ORDER BY Sum(SLTransactionSummary.InvoiceValue) DESC
```

Comment: Is this in Sage or SQL? does not seem like Excel though so why tag Excel?

Comment: Move the condition `SLTransactionSummary.TransactionDate Between ? And ?` to the ON clause and remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: @ solar Mike - Sorry, it's a query done in the SQL editor with the data being put into excel. I wasn't aware if this would make a difference so added the tag.

@ forpas1 - I'm not exactly sure where to add it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `HAVING` clause is requiring a match.  You also need to check for `NULL` values:

```
HAVING COALESCE(Sum(SLTransactionSummary.InvoiceValue), 0) Between 0 And 50000
```

Otherwise the value will be `NULL` when there are no matches -- and the `BETWEEN` returns `NULL` which filters out rows.

EDIT:

You also have a `WHERE` clause that is undoing the `LEFT JOIN`.  Try this version:

```
SELECT ca.CustomerAccountNumber,
       Sum(ts.InvoiceValue) AS SumnvoiceValue
FROM SWA_live2.dbo.SLCustomerAccount ca LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     SWA_live2.dbo.SLTransactionSummary ts
     ON ca.SLCustomerAccountID = sl.SLCustomerAccountID AND
        ts.TransactionDate Between ? And ?
GROUP BY ca.CustomerAccountNumber
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(ts.InvoiceValue), 0) Between 0 And 50000
ORDER BY Sum(ts.InvoiceValue) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, however I seem to be getting the same amount of results having added this code.

Comment: Thanks again, however I get parameter errors: 'Invalid parameter number' followed by 'Invalid descriptor Index'. After looking around it may be something to do with the source being between SQL and SQL native server. 

If it helps, this being pulled by a spreadsheet from sage using SQL query.

Comment: @Barty . . . I simplified the `FROM` clause syntax.  Perhaps that is no suitable to your SQL interface.